# System.Access Violation Exception While calling C++ Dll in .Net Application

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, managed

I am implementing C++ Dll in the C#.

My Wrapper.h file:

`

```
    class __declspec(dllexport) TestClass
     {   
      public:
              int value;
              TestClass(int value):value(value)
              {
              }
             ~TestClass()
              {
              }
     }
```

`

My Wrapper.cpp File

```
   #include "stdafx.h"

   #include "WrapperApplication.h"
```

My C# code

```
 public unsafe class Message:IDisposable
{
   private TestStruct* _testStruct;
   private IntPtr* _oldVTable;
      [DllImport(@"WrapperApplication.dll", EntryPoint = "??0TestClass@WrapperApplication@@QAE@H@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
   extern static IntPtr Test(TestStruct* testStruct, int value);

   public Message(int value)
   {
       _testStruct=(TestStruct*)Memory.Alloc(sizeof(TestStruct));

       Test(_testStruct, value);
   }
   #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {

        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

My TestStruct.cs file:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
  public unsafe struct TestStruct
  {
    public IntPtr* vtable;
    public int value;
  }
```

I have to Call CPP dll with the help of the **Vtable** in the .Net Application.
I have created TestStruct.cs file as replica of My Cpp class.
And trying to Call the CPP constructor in the C# constructor.
But at the line   **Test(_testStruct, value);** throws the System.AccessViolation Exception as Attempted to read or Write the memory.It is often indication that other memory is corrupt. The values for _teststruct, value in the Test ctor comes but still it  throws the Exception.I have tried many ways but failed to get the solution. Please let me know where I am wrong in the implementaion.
So Any Help would Appreciated.

Comment: Test is the CPP constructor name which i am  exported in the C#.

Comment: (oops, how silly of me) WAIT, your class as it is declared doesn't *have* a vtable, since it has no virtual functions. However, that's not a reason for the constructor call to cause an access violation.

Comment: Yes.I have to call C++ Dll in the C# by using Vtables and I know  it needs  some Virtual functions in the CPP Class... but at constructor it throws the Access Violation Exception

Comment: I have looked at the article. Can you post the code of Memory.Alloc()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be not to call directly a C++-interface DLL from C#. With this premise, two ways appear before you:

- Give your DLL a flat C interface, or a Component Object Model (COM) interface. This will make it callable from most platforms and languages.
- Keep the DLL as-is, but call it from C++/CLI code instead of C# code. It's the reason C++/CLI exists, after all: To make this kind of glue code between .Net Framework applications and unmanaged libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But my requirement is to call C++ dll in the .Net Application and I refered the [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/12/08/inheriting-from-a-native-c-class-in-c.aspx).please go through this Link and let me know .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling unmanaged code first make sure you `Dispose()` the unmanaged resources. There is a way you can catch the exception thrown by unmanaged code (*if the failing module is your unmanaged component*). Decorate your `Message()` method with `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` attribute which will catch any exception thrown by unmanaged code.

```
  [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
   public Message(int value)
   {

    try
      {
         _testStruct=(TestStruct*)Memory.Alloc(sizeof(TestStruct));

         Test(_testStruct, value);
      }
    Catch(AccessViolationException ex)
      {
         //Read the exception here
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.I have done the Changes as per  your Suggestion.but still it throws the Exception at the Same Line.